# How to replace SFListView into Xamarin Forms ListView

Tags: c#, performance, listview, xamarin, syncfusion

For some reason when I use SfListView the list is not loading on time , it seems the page loads way faster than the list.
In context , the service that fills the list is full of linQ selections . Iam not sure if these were the reasons why the list doesn't appear on time .
After some research, when I use a regular xamarin forms or collection view it does show the items on time.
I choose syncfusion because it is easier to display an inner list with less code on my end. However, my frustration is so real now that I'd rather do whatever it takes to get these 2 list working.

**Question**
How can I replace what I have to match xamarin forms list binding properties?
How can I replace SFListview into a Listview in the below example?
Is there any other thing that I could add to force the page to load in delay or until the list gets filled?
If I use a hardcode list not a problem . I just dont understand
**NOTES:**
When I use xamarin forms HotReload , I can inmediately see the list . but I have to force the refresh or something like that .

1. List item

I tried the following

```
public class OuterListViewBehavior : Behavior<SfListView>
    {
        SfListView ListView;
        protected override void OnAttachedTo(SfListView bindable)
        {
            ListView = bindable;
            
            ListView.Loaded += ListView_Loaded;
            base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        }
        private async void ListView_Loaded(object sender, ListViewLoadedEventArgs e)
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            ListView.RefreshView();
        }
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<StackLayout x:Name="mainGrid" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="4">

            <sync:SfListView x:Name="outerlist" ItemsSource="{Binding ActiveDates}" 

                              AutoFitMode="DynamicHeight"

                              SelectionMode ="Single"

                              IsScrollBarVisible="False"

                              ItemSpacing="0"

                              TapCommand="{Binding TapGestureCommand}">


                <!--customize on item tapped-->

                <sync:SfListView.ItemTemplate >

                    <DataTemplate>

                        <Grid Grid.RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                            <Grid x:Name="grid" RowSpacing="0" Padding="0,5,0,0">

                                <yummy:PancakeView Margin="4" WidthRequest="60" Padding="4" BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="4" HorizontalOptions="Center" >

                                    <yummy:PancakeView.Border>

                                        <yummy:Border Thickness="4" Color="red" />

                                    </yummy:PancakeView.Border>

                                    <StackLayout>

                                        <Label Text="{Binding Month}" TextColor="#2A86E3" FontSize="16" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0" >
                                            <Label.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" 
                                                             Binding="{Binding completed}"
                                                             Value="true">
                                                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="LightBlue"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Label.Triggers>
                                        </Label>

                                    </StackLayout>

                                </yummy:PancakeView>

                            </Grid>

                            <Grid Grid.RowDefinitions="1,80" IsVisible="{Binding completed}" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0" Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="5" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                                <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="LightGray" />

                                <!--Building list inner list -->

                                <helpers:ExtendedListView x:Name="innerListView"

                                           SelectionMode ="None"

                                           Grid.Row="1"

                                           TapCommand="{Binding Path=BindingContext.TapInnerListGestureCommand,

                                           Source={x:Reference outerlist}}"

                                           IsScrollBarVisible="False"

                                           ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BindingContext.Activehours,

                                           Source={x:Reference outerlist}}" >

                                    <helpers:ExtendedListView.ItemTemplate>

                                        <DataTemplate>

                                            <Grid Grid.RowDefinitions="Auto" >

                                                <yummy:PancakeView Margin="3" WidthRequest="60" Padding="4" BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="4" HorizontalOptions="Center" >

                                                    <yummy:PancakeView.Border>

                                                        <yummy:Border Thickness="4" Color="#D9DADB" />

                                                    </yummy:PancakeView.Border>

                                                    <StackLayout>

                                                        <Label Text="{Binding body}" TextColor="#2A86E3" FontSize="16" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0">
                                                            <Label.Triggers>
                                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" 
                                                             Binding="{Binding completed}"
                                                             Value="true">
                                                                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>
                                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                            </Label.Triggers>
                                                        </Label>

                                                    </StackLayout>

                                                </yummy:PancakeView>

                                            </Grid>

                                        </DataTemplate>

                                    </helpers:ExtendedListView.ItemTemplate>

                                </helpers:ExtendedListView>

                            </Grid>

                        </Grid>

                    </DataTemplate>

                </sync:SfListView.ItemTemplate>

            </sync:SfListView>

        </StackLayout>
```

**ViewModel**

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {

             await GetListAsync(id, buid);


           });
```

Comment: its rarely a good idea to nest LIstViews.  And if your root problem is caused by the time it takes to load the data, where is the code that actually does that?

Comment: @Jason thanks for reply, the code is really long I have there a bunch of queries around 7 of them , since that call is been use to feed other lists or items in the page .what causes my confusion is that if I use a collectionview or a regular listview it does load.maybe there is something that helps me autorefresh that particular after it gets to the view?

Answer (score 1):

If the cause is the time of getting data from the database, you can put the method of loading data in a Task async methdod and use the Task.Wait() in the page's Onappearing method. Such as:

create a method in your viewmodel

```
 public async Task getDataFromSQlite()
 {
     //do the linQ selections
 }
```

use the following code in your page.cs

```
  public Page()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PageViewModel viewmodel = new PageViewModel();
        this.BindingContext = viewmodel;

        //You can also call the method here
        //Task result = viewmodel.getDataFromSQlite()
        //result.Wait();
    }
  
  protected override void OnAppearing()
  {
        Task result = viewmodel.getDataFromSQlite()
        result.Wait();
        base.OnAppearing();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

We suspect that the delay is caused by the Delay provided in the Loaded event. Please remove the delay to resolve the reported scenario.

```
private async void ListView_Loaded(object sender, ListViewLoadedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    ListView.RefreshView();
}
```